# Extract string of numbers

Tags: regex, jira

I’m trying to set up a mail handler in JIRA. I have the following possible formats and I need to makes sure the string contains `Case [number] - New Comment Added`.

So for the following, it should return `123456` (could be more digits, but no spaces between digits)

```
RE: Vendor Support Case 123456 - New Comment Added
Case 123456 - New Comment Added
```

Comment: could you please clearly state what is your input and what is your desired output?

Comment: /[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*/

Comment: Sry try '/.*Case (\d+).*/'

Comment: Can you capture the number as a group, or do you need to match just the number with the whole regex?

Comment: @Bohemian I can capture as a group

Answer (score 4):

Here is one option that also finds the strings before and after the number, but does not make them part of the match:

```
(?:Case\s*)(\d+)(?: - New Comment Added)
```

`(?:)` is a non-capturing group in regex - i.e. it finds the string, but it discards it and does not add it to the final result. Just be careful not to put an extra pair of parenthesis around it, as it would capture it and make it part of the final match.

Comment: you don't need any of those square brackets

Answer (score 0):

If your tool supports look-arounds:

```
(?<=Case )\d+(?= - New Comment Added)
```

The entire match is your case number. You can remove `(?= - New Comment Added)` if you don't require `" - New Comment Added"` to follow the number.